# How to stop thread in many methods called?

Tags: thread-safety, pthreads

I want to stop executing the thread, but after looking up the information on the Internet, I think it is a very good way to end the thread by the flag, but my usage scenario is that the thread's run method continuously calls 20 methods, I set the flag. How do you end up with these 20 methods?
Such as the following code

```
void thread_start(){
    new Thread(){
        public void run(){
            callMethod1();
            callMethod2();
        }
    }.start();
}


void callMethod1(){
    foo1();
    foo2();
    foo3();
    foo4();
    foo5();
    ...
    foo66();  // I want stop thread here ,how stop it by a taging  which like  if(running==false) stop above thread
    ...
    foo98();
    foo99();
    foo100();;
}

void callMethod2(){

}

void foo1(){}
void foo2(){}
void foo3(){}
void foo4(){}
........
void foo30(){}
```

how to stop it in method which is : foo66()

I want to stop it with a flag ,but I didnt know how to do it

// like follow code

```
new Thread(){
    public void run(){
        .....
        if(isRunning==false){
            return;
        }
        .....
    }
}.start();
```

ying yu tai lan le ,fan yi hao low ,nin cou huo zhe kan ba

Comment: Update a flag (isRunning=false) after foo66(); and return immediately. Check that flag in run() block (as you have done already).

Comment: if use isRunning that need to add this check in each function （may be 100 times）,and in fact ,not sure in foo66 may be  foo55 foo32